# How do I persist nested (MongoDB) entities with Panache Reactive and Mutiny?

Tags: mongodb, quarkus, quarkus-panache, mutiny

I am having trouble using Mutiny. I have 2 entities:

```
public class Rating extends ReactivePanacheMongoEntity {    
    public String name;
}
```

and

```
public class Product extends ReactivePanacheMongoEntity {    
    public List<Rating> ratings = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Now I would like to create a rating, persist it and add it to the list of ratings of a product.

```
public Uni<Product> addRatingToProduct(String productId, String name) {

    Rating rating = new Rating();
    rating.name= name;
    Uni<Rating> ratingUni = rating.persistOrUpdate();

    // Now I need to add the rating to the product:
    Uni<Product> productUni = Product.findEntity(productId);

}
```

I tried something along the lines of

```
return ratingUni.map(r -> {
    Uni<Product> productUni = Product.findEntity(productId).map(p -> {
        p.ratings.add(r);
        return p;
    });
    return productUni;
});
```

but these nested maps feel wrong, and the return Type ended up being a nested Uni.

I also tried Uni.combine(), but to no avail...

I thought that switching to a Reactive Programming with mutiny would be easier, but examples are scarce and the quarkus panache docs are rather superficial

Comment: So you want to first save a `Rating` and then update the `Product` to include it?

Comment: Yes. This is how I would have done it non reactivly. Persist the child entity, then add it to the parent. Is this not how it should be done in a reactive context? :)

Comment: It's correct. But you probably need `flatMap` instead of `map`

Comment: The FlatMap solved the compilation Problem, but the rating was not being added to the product. I ended up with a simpler solution, see below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up removing the "Relational DB Style" entity-in-another-entity and added a reference to ProductId in Rating (as suggested [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/))

```
public class Rating extends ReactivePanacheMongoEntity {    
    public ObjectId productId;
    public String name;
}
```

thus I only need to persist this new entity.